How to get SEPOLIA TEST ETHER from TESTNET FAUCET without ETH balance in METAMASK account
I tried to get SEPOLIA TEST ETHER from various TESTNET FAUCETS.
But all of them require minimum ETH balance in my METAMASK account.
I dont have any ETH balance in METAMASK.
I tried.
https://www.alchemy.com/faucets/ethereum-sepolia
https://sepolia-faucet.pk910.de/
https://www.infura.io/faucet/sepolia
https://chainstack.com/sepolia-faucet/
https://faucet.quicknode.com/ethereum/sepolia
https://www.sepoliafaucet.io/
pls help solve.
thanks
Uday


Git Passport-Coinbase to Metamask.
connecting Git Passport to GitHub.
Git Passport with COINBASE wallet when I click on First and Last passphrase words its keeping on verifying. not connecting.

You can use Sepolia PoW Faucet, that just requires Gitcoin Passport with a score >= 2 as of now.
You can easily achieve a passport score >=2, just by connecting some of your socials.

And, then you can start mining Sepolia-Eth easily in no time.


Or, you can use Chainlink faucet to get 0.1 Sepolia-Eth, or any other native testnet token depending on your need (as long as it’s available in the list). They’re not asking for any mainnet funds availability or so.

Brother i have tried this too, as i have mentioned they require minimum passport score. it giving error: "The faucet denied starting a session because your wallet does not meet the minimum passport score."

Yes Awais. But, you can easily get the minimum required passport score (i.e., 2 as of now), just by connecting some of your socials, as I've mentioned.

Thanks SYED ASAD KAZMI for your detailed answer, I managed 1.04 Passport score with Google, Discord. Others are asking to solve Puzzles etc.                                        Can you suggest some easy way to increase score to 2.                                                       Also Is required score 2 or 20 as in website it mentions 20.

@Udayarajangauthaman, minimum score of 2 is required for mining Sepolia-Eth using that faucet as of now. You can try connecting LinkedIn and GitHub as well, it would potentially increase your score further.

@Udayarajangauthaman if you connect linkedin, github and discord your score would be 9.12 and then refresh the passport score then mine it, wait 1 hour it will automatically give you the claim option.

Okay Awais Ahmad and Syed

This is absolutely ridiculous. Everyone demands SOMETHING. Every damned faucet DEMANDS that you give them something. Register, do whatever else. Your time, your Twitter, your other socials. Whatever. For a bloody virtual priceless crappy 0.05 testnet ETH.

Try Chainlink faucet, they are not demanding anything.

After much exploration of various links, I finally stumbled upon the Google Cloud Web3 Portal today. You'll receive 0.05 faucets. Additionally, Alchemy mentioned that you should have 0.001 ETH in mainnet funds to access Sepolia. However, other links mention the requirement of points, mining, or undergoing maintenance.

Thanks Awais Ahmad, I was able to get 0.05 faucets(/day) by your answer. Thanks for the help.

Sounds good @Udayarajangauthaman kindly accept the solution.

Google Cloud Web3 provides 0.05 Sepolia ETH. program runs once then gas limit issue. Google Cloud Web3,Git passport - good solutions. any other way to get like get 0.001 ETH required by other SEPOLIA FAUCETS.

There are lots of free testnet faucets, I'm using one from getblock.io
https://getblock.io/faucet/
I'm not really sure if it requires some ETH on your Metamask already, but I'm more about that it's not, but you better check it for yourself
It's also available for ETH, Arbitrum, Optimism, zksync, scroll, linea, Polygon, and some other networks.
